# React adds an "undefined" class to components

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have multiple components in my project, most of which are simple containers for specific content, with a bit of styling. They typically look like this—

```js
function Portion(props) {
    return (
        <div id={props.id} className={`portion ${props.className}`}>
            {props.children}
        </div>
    )
}
```

I have the extra `${props.className}` so that it’s easy to add more classes if need be. Now, the problem is that if there are no extra classes for that element, React adds an `undefined` class.

[image: React undefined class]

How can I avoid that?

Comment: initialize `props.className=""`

Comment: set default prop values

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using

```
${props.className || ""}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can add a condition;

```
className={`portion ${props.className || ””}`}
```

Comment: Right answer, but the other guy beat you by 22 seconds.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2):

You can add a default value to the className if you destructure your props

```
function Portion({className = '', id, children}) {
    return (
        <div id={id} className={`portion ${className}`}>
            {children}
        </div>
    )
}
```